# jsf static list won't show up in datatable

Tags: jsf, el

I'm trying to get a list to show in datatable from managed bean to JSF page but it doesn't work.
it's telling me " not records found " .

JSF managed bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestController {
    private List<Rhnom> list = new ArrayList<Rhnom>();
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("s1");
        add("s2");
        add("s3");
    }}; 
    //getters and setters
```

JSF page :

```
<p:dataTable value="#{tesController.list2}" var="type">
    <p:column headerText="Lib">
        <h:outputText value="#{type}">
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: can you post the code about jsf.config?

Comment: Uhhhhhhh so if you don't use a `p:datatable` but a plain `#{tesController.list2}` (!!!)  in your pages, something IS shown? And s non-static list works? I doubt it, please run your application in development mode and debug... you have a very clear and obivous typo

Comment: yeah i was missing a char , thanks

Comment: Please remove the question then... and learn why you should make a [mcve]... You (**YOU**) narrow things down before posting a question. Often you find the solution then.

Answer (score -2):

I consider that you have problems with the implementation

Link

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml

Example

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>
 
    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>
 
    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>
 
    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Managebean

```
@Named("dtBasicView")
@ViewScoped
public class BasicView implements Serializable {
     
    private List<Car> cars;
     
    @Inject
    private CarService service;
 
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cars = service.createCars(10);
    }
     
    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }
 
    public void setService(CarService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Java Class

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class CarService {
     
    private final static String[] colors;
     
    private final static String[] brands;
     
    static {
        colors = new String[10];
        colors[0] = "Black";
        colors[1] = "White";
        colors[2] = "Green";
        colors[3] = "Red";
        colors[4] = "Blue";
        colors[5] = "Orange";
        colors[6] = "Silver";
        colors[7] = "Yellow";
        colors[8] = "Brown";
        colors[9] = "Maroon";
         
        brands = new String[10];
        brands[0] = "BMW";
        brands[1] = "Mercedes";
        brands[2] = "Volvo";
        brands[3] = "Audi";
        brands[4] = "Renault";
        brands[5] = "Fiat";
        brands[6] = "Volkswagen";
        brands[7] = "Honda";
        brands[8] = "Jaguar";
        brands[9] = "Ford";
    }
     
    public List<Car> createCars(int size) {
        List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
            list.add(new Car(getRandomId(), getRandomBrand(), getRandomYear(), getRandomColor(), getRandomPrice(), getRandomSoldState()));
        }
         
        return list;
    }
     
    private String getRandomId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
    }
     
    private int getRandomYear() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);
    }
     
    private String getRandomColor() {
        return colors[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }
     
    private String getRandomBrand() {
        return brands[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }
     
    private int getRandomPrice() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 100000);
    }
     
    private boolean getRandomSoldState() {
        return (Math.random() > 0.5) ? true: false;
    }
     
    public List<String> getColors() {
        return Arrays.asList(colors);
    }
     
    public List<String> getBrands() {
        return Arrays.asList(brands);
    }
}
```

Comment: so effectively your comment on the question is 'compare with the showcase, it works there'

Comment: .. and this does not help at all with the faced issue, as the cause was a typo in the bean name.